# Remove duplicate values from Array of Dictionaries

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have an array in swift and I want to remove duplicate one single value from duplicate values(with their value) like that :

```
var myArray = [
        [
            "name": "John",
            "age": 21
        ],
        [
            "name": "Bob",
            "age": 35
        ],
        [
            "name": "Nyan",
            "age": 20
        ],
        [
            "name": "Nyan",
            "age": 20
        ]
    ]
```

I use the following codes to remove duplicate values

```
for i in 0...myArray.count - 1{
        if(myArray[i]["name"] as! String == "Nyan"){
                print(myArray.remove(at: i))
        }
}

print(myArray)
```

That doesn't reduce the myArray.count and give **Fatal error: Index out of range** 
Desired output :

```
[
    "name": "John",
    "age": 21
],
[
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 35
],
[
    "name": "Nyan",
    "age": 20
]
```

Comment: After removing the item at index 2 (zero based) the counter is still 4 but there is no item at index 3 anymore. You have to remove the items `reversed` starting at the highest index to avoid the out-of-range exception.

Comment: Note that `myDict` is an `Array` (of Dictionaries), that's clearly a misleading var name.

Comment: update the misleading var name. Thanks

Comment: What is your actual goal? With your current code (even if it worked) you'd remove all elements matching your deletion criteria, not just one of the duplicates. Do you want to only keep one element if there are repeating ones? Can there be several repeating elements?

Comment: I just want to remove the one element that is duplicate and want to keep one element if there are repeating ones. And yes there can be several repeating elements.

Comment: Do you only care about duplicate keys, or does the key **and** the value need to match before you consider it a duplicate? (e.g. are `["name": "Nyan", "age": 20]`and `["name": "Nyan", "age": 45]`duplicates?

Comment: There are only ["name": "Nyan", "age": 20] in array and there will be no duplication like ["name": "Nyan", "age": 45]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please use a filter or compactMap instead of For loop:

```
let array: [[String : Any]] = [["Name":"Alice", "Age":"15"],
                                       ["Name":"Bob", "Age":"53"],
                                       ["Name":"Cathy", "Age":"12"],
                                       ["Name":"Bob", "Age":"83"],
                                       ["Name":"Denise", "Age":"88"],
                                       ["Name":"Alice", "Age":"44"]]

        var set = Set<String>()
        let arraySet: [[String : Any]] = array.compactMap {
            guard let name = $0["Name"] as? String else {return nil }
            return set.insert(name).inserted ? $0 : nil
        }

        print(arraySet)
```

Answer (score 7):

Rather than removing the items I recommend to create a new array.

You need also a helper array to collect the names. If the `names` array does not contain the current name, add the name to the array and the item to the `result`

```
let myArray = [
    ["name": "John","age": 21],
    ["name": "Bob", "age": 35],
    ["name": "Nyan", "age": 20],
    ["name": "Nyan", "age": 20]]

var names = [String]()
var result = [[String:Any]]()

for item in myArray {
    let name = item["name"] as! String
    if !names.contains(name) {
        names.append(name)
        result.append(item)
    }
}

print(result)
```

And – just for fun – a solution using a struct which conforms to `Hashable`.

Create a `Set` from the array (which makes the items unique) and then create an array from the set.

```
struct Person : Hashable { let name : String; let age : Int }

let myArray = [Person(name: "John", age: 21), Person(name: "Bob", age: 35), Person(name: "Nyan", age: 20), Person(name: "Nyan", age: 20)]
let result = Array(Set<Person>(myArray))

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func removeDuplicates(_ arrayOfDicts: [[String: String]]) -> [[String:String]] {
var removeDuplicates = [[String: String]]()
var arrOfDict = [String]()
for dict in arrayOfDicts {
if let name = dict["messageTo"], ! arrOfDict.contains(name) {
    removeDuplicates.append(dict)
    arrOfDict.append(name)
}
}
return removeDuplicates
}
```

Try This!

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Answer (score 0):

you are removing an element of the array as you are iterating through the array which will screw with `myArray.count` while not changing `i`.

you could try this:

```
let myArray = myArray.filter { element in
  if myArray.filter({ $0["name"] == element["name"] }).count == 1 {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

This filters the array to only include elements that only have 1 element matching the name.

Comment: ** let myArray = myArray.filter { $0["name"] as! String != "Nyan" } **
This one remove all the values of "Nyan". And only two items remain

Comment: If you truly want to remove duplicates, then yes, you can't hardcode the value.  You just hardcoded the value of "Nyan" in your question, which confused me a little

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in generic collection type which does this for you, it's called a Set. [Sets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set) are a collection type, like arrays, but only store unique values and do not order them. Depending on your use case, it may be beneficial to replace your usage of arrays with sets. But you can also use sets temporarily to remove duplicate values and then convert the set back to an array. However, sets require that their members conform to the [Hashable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable) protocol. The Hashable protocol this is what determines if the values are duplicates. Dictionaries are very simple to work with in some ways, but don't give the compiler enough information about what they contain to do anything useful.

The following is an example which changes your member type to a struct which conforms to Hashable, uses a set to remove duplicates, and then converts the set to an array.

```
struct Person:Hashable
{
     var name:String
     var age:Int
}

var myArray:[Person] = [
     Person( name:"John", age:21 ),
     Person( name:"Bob", age:35 ),
     Person( name:"Nyan", age:20 ),
     Person( name:"Nyan", age:20 ),
]

let mySet = Set<Person>( myArray )
myArray = Array( mySet )
```